# React/Express - required props 'undefined' in match/RouterContext

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

I'm working on implementing server-side rendering for my React/Express app - the app is actually working as desired, but I'm getting a warning on my server related to `match()` and `RouterContext` that I'd like to understand and resolve.

Basically, in the callback function for `match`, the arguments `(err, redirect, props)` are all evaluating as `undefined`.

`index.js` (Express app root):

```
'use strict'
require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
});

const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const React = require('react')
const reactDomServer = require('react-dom/server')
const routes = require('./src/routes.jsx')
const reactRouter = require('react-router')
let { match, RouterContext, createRoutes } = reactRouter

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    match({ routes: createRoutes(routes), location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
        const appHtml = renderToString(React.createElement(RouterContext, props))
        res.send(renderPage(appHtml))
    })
})
```

So if I throw a `console.log()` in for `err`, `redirect`, and `props`, they all come back as `undefined`. This causes my server to return the warning

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `router` is marked as required in `RouterContext`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in RouterContext
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `location` is marked as required in `RouterContext`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in RouterContext
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `routes` is marked as required in `RouterContext`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in RouterContext
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `params` is marked as required in `RouterContext`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in RouterContext
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `components` is marked as required in `RouterContext`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in RouterContext
Warning: Failed child context type: The child context `router` is marked as required in `RouterContext`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in RouterContext
```

Again, to my surprise, my app seems to work just fine - I can refresh pages, access urls directly (i.e. 'localhost:3000/person/1234'), but these warnings persist. Maybe I don't understand the needs of `RouterContext` (likely).

Regardless, I would like to resolve this, because I want to use those arguments to set up some conditionals... any guidance on this would be much appreciated.

**Update**
I've realized that `err` and `redirect` are supposed to default to `undefined` (unless there's an error or redirect), but no matter what I do, `props` seems to be stuck on undefined as well.

From https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/match.html: "If all three parameters are `undefined`, this means that there was no route found matching the given location."

But I don't understand - the app seems to work fine. What gives?

Comment: `err` is supposed to default to `undefined` unless there is an error. if `props` is undefined too, doesnt mean there are some errors?

Comment: Yes - see the 'Update' I made at the bottom of my question. You were right about not using createRoutes, though - it's not appropriate here. I figured it out, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @taha for pointing me in the right direction on this. Turns out that the problem was both my use of `createRoutes()` and the fact that I was not correctly accessing the routes.

The call to `match` needs to be

```
match({ routes: routes.default, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => { /* etc. */ }
```

Comment: `routes: routes.default` :) wasn't that difficult! I'm glad you solved your problem :D happy coding

Comment: I've easily spent a full day bashing my head against something this simple.

Answer (score 0):

`createRoutes` has been removed from **react-router** (few releases ago).

```
let { match, RouterContext, createRoutes } = reactRouter
// 'createRoutes' is undefined
```

You should create/prepare your routes manually and export it as a standalone module (the snippet below is taken from the [official docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/13-server-rendering))

```
module.exports = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}>
      <Route path="/repos/:userName/:repoName" component={Repo}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
  </Route>
)
```

Comment: I'm using `react-router` v 3.0.2, and `createRoutes` is a valid function in that version, and `const routes = require('./src/routes.jsx')` refers to a standalone module just like you've shown. Hmmm...